# How do you create a user with no password?

Tags: osx, users, password, login

In os X it's possible to have users without passwords. If you inspect them with `dscl` their password show up as `*`. This is used for system users such as users for databases like `mysql`, `pgsql` etc. What's nice about this is that these users doesn't show up at the login screen and you can't login as them without `sudo` etc.

After deleting such a user trying some things out I wanted to recreate it, but couldn't. I could manage to get a user with a blank password and I could set the password to `*`. But none had the same effect as above, as the user showed up on my login screen.

How do you create such a user?

Comment: On Linux, you pass the --disabled-password flag to adduser. Maybe OS X has something similar in its command line repertoire?

Comment: Did you mean; user can log in without a password or can't log in at all because no password is set?

Comment: I notice you didn't accept an answer... one requirement to stay out of the various xdm lists is having a significantly low userid. on many systems `useradd` starts adding id's at 1000, and the login managers won't show user id's below that, but everything above. so though it's not an answer to this question, it might be the resolution to the problem. please note that 1000 is arbitrary and may be lower or higher on your distribution. To fix just modify the user entry in `/etc/passwd` to have a lower uid. *Now for me to go ask similar question.*

Comment: @xenoterracide: When I recreated the user, I gave it the old ID, it was the pgsql user I deleted which has an id of one higher than the mysql one, so I'm sure it didn't have any impact in this case, but thanks for the info anyways.

Answer (score 6):

You can run `passwd --delete <username>` after creating the user with `adduser`. After this, you'll be able to login without entering a password.

Comment: I think that's the exact opposite of what is being asked for here.

Comment: At first, I thought this was the right (or best) answer, until I've re-read the OP's question, which mentions for "system user" and not show up on "login screen".  This method will show up on login screen and you can 'sudo' using this method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `usermod`, which will disable the password using an `!` rather than an `*`.

```
usermod -L <username>
```

From the man page on usermod:

```
-L, --lock Lock a user's password. This puts a '!' in front of the encrypted password, effectively disabling the password.
```

Answer (score 3):

A user in /etc/passwd with  home directory of /dev/null and shell of /sbin/nologin, can be used for sudo ing commands, but can't actually be logged into, for example;

from my /etc/passwd

```
tcpdump:x:104:441:added by portage for tcpdump:/dev/null:/sbin/nologin
```

I half remember this will make it disappear from the XDM login screen too, but I don't use XDM anymore, so that's a guess :-)

Comment: This is the right answer because the OP asked for account which you cannot 'sudo' or show up on "login screen", by setting to '/sbin/nologin' for shell.  One thing to note is because the OP asked for "system user", should also mention that 'useradd --system' should be used to create UID in low number (as portage/ebuild does)

Answer (score 3):

Using `dscl` would give

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/myuser ""
```

Comment: This, unlike most of the answers above it... actually worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Ubuntu you can swap in the password for the Ubuntu user in /etc/shadow  check out this article:

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/creating-a-passwordless-account-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain about OSX, but on FreeBSD you can use:

```
pw add user mymuser -g mygroup -s /nonexistent -h -
```

the value of `-` passed to the `-h` option tells `pw` to set the password field in master.passwd to `*`, thus creating a no-login account.  Setting the shell isn't strictly necessary, but avoids a shell check from /etc/pw.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the password field empty for the user in the `passwd` file will work.

Answer (score -1):

On Linux I use:

```
sudo useradd -r -p \* -s /sbin/nologin -c "Comment My Daemon,,,"  -d "/var/uuu"  myuser
```

The next alternative must be more cross platform (if `-r` option is not available):

```
sudo useradd -K UID_MIN=100 -K UID_MAX=499 -K GID_MIN=100 -K GID_MAX=499 -p \* -s /sbin/nologin -c "Comment My Daemon,,,"  -d "/var/uuu"  myuser
```

Here:

- password in **/etc/shadow** will be setted to `*`. Without `-p \*` it will be `!`
- shell will be `/sbin/nologin` (You can use `/bin/false` too, but I think the `/bin` may be mounted too late on some systems). So user can't login
- `-d` sets user's homedir

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

Here `-r` creates a system user:

*This flag is used to create a system account. That is, a user with a `UID` lower than the value of `UID_MIN` defined in **/etc/login.defs** and whose password does not expire. Note that useradd will not create a home directory for such an user, regardless of the default setting in **/etc/login.defs**. You have to specify `-m` option if you want a home directory for a system account to be created. **This is an option added by Red Hat**.*

Option `-r` may not be present on your system. So to create a system user, that is not shown on your login screen, I think, you can use `-K` option. Something like: `-K UID_MIN=100 -K UID_MAX=499`. You can try option like:

```
-K UID_MAX=$(cat /etc/login.defs | grep ^UID_MIN | awk '{print $2}')
```

to automatically determine you `UID_MAX`, but I've not tested on OS X. You'll need use `SYS_UID_MAX` for `UID_MIN` if it's uncommented in **/etc/login.defs**

The same is for `GID_MAX` and `GID_MIN` for the system group id. (See `GID_MIN` and if uncommented `SYS_GID_MAX` in **/etc/login.defs** to use as `GID_MAX`)