# sudo for users with empty passwords

Tags: sudo

I want sudo to behave like this, for all users:

1. If the user currently has a non-empty password, prompt for the password.
2. If the user currently has an empty password, either prompt for the password and accept the empty string, or don't prompt at all and permit.

Is this possible? Right now, I have (1) but this is what happens for a user with an empty password:

```
$ sudo echo
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Alternatively, I can switch off password checking per-user, but that's not what I want, because the user might set a password later, and then sudo should prompt for it.

Comment: You want accounts that have no password to be able to run any command as root? Why bother having passwords at all for any account? You can just `chmod ug+x /bin/su` because that's the net effect of your desire.

Comment: That fails condition 1. I want users to be prompted for a password if they have one.

Comment: @AshleyYakeley so they can just su to the account with no password and then sudo from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in my PAM "auth" script: the script was terminating without ever getting an "ok" or "done".

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this is possible because `sudo` will not know that a user doesn't have a password or that it's the empty string until it (`sudo`) presents the password, empty or otherwise, to the PAM module for validation. Therefore it will always need to request the password from the user, before proceeding.

Your only recourse here is to configure users that do not require the use of a password with the `NOPASSWD` option in your sudoers file. But this is highly insecure, and I'd recommend you seriously consider what your ultimate goal is here before proceeding with that method.

### ...so I don't care about security...

#### First set a "blank" password

This U&L Q&A titled: [How do you create a user with no password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128/how-do-you-create-a-user-with-no-password) suggested using this method which worked for me.

```
$ sudo passwd --delete samtest
Removing password for user samtest.
passwd: Success
```

#### Now test it out

Now add a line like this to your `/etc/sudoers` file. **NOTE:** Always edit this file using `sudo visudo`.

```
samtest ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Now try logging in as user "samtest" without any password.

```
$ su - samtest
$
```

Now try using this account using `sudo`:

```
$ whoami
samtest

$ sudo echo

$
```

Comment: This will be running in a VM, with no security at all: there will be a default user with no password, auto-login, and root access. However, the user can set a password purely to protect themselves from their own mistakes.

Comment: @AshleyYakeley - are you making a standard type of system account that you'll distribute with the VM? If so I'd do the NOPASSWD for it in sudoers file then.

Comment: I wouldn't mind sudo asking for a password, and the user just hitting enter, but it doesn't. It just gives the output above.

Comment: @AshleyYakeley - how did you set the password as blank? I'd do it using `passwd <username>`, or try other methods mentioned here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128/how-do-you-create-a-user-with-no-password

Comment: @AshleyYakeley - see updates.

Comment: I created the user with `useradd --password ''`

Comment: @AshleyYakeley - and if you create the password as I described does that change things? Notice what you wanted to do worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Wondering why `sudo` via a console works while it prompts for a password over SSH?

At least on Ubuntu 16.04, the default policy in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` contains:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

The [pam_unix(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_unix.8.html) manual documents that `nullok_secure` permits empty passwords only when using one of the TTYs in `/etc/securetty`. If this limitation is not desired, one could replace `nullok_secure` by `nullok`.

Alternatively one can allow one specific user to use empty passwords by means of a `NOPASSWD` sudoers file as described by slm.